# Counting the number of specific type of variables in Yacc

Tags: yacc, text-parsing

I've just started to learn how to use Lex and Yacc. I'm using the grammar described in these sites(http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l-2011.html, http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y-2011.html).

I'm currently trying to apply the Yacc grammar to the code I'm working on: Counting specific type of variables(e.g. counting number of int variables) or count how many arrays have been declared.

In definition section, I additionally wrote like this:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int num;
%}
```

For yacc to recognize such variable as int, I want to change the code below in rule section:

```
declaration 
    : declaration_specifiers ';'
    | declaration_specifiers init_declarator_list ';'
    ;
```

like this:

```
declaration
    : type_specifier init_declarator_list ';'
    | type_specifier IDENTIFIER '[' primary_expression ']' ';'
    ;
```

or to be specific, if I were to count INT variables or array consisted of int, the code might be written like this:

```
declaration
    : INT init_declarator_list ';' {num++;}
    | INT IDENTIFIER '[' primary_expression ']' ';' {num++;}
    ;
```

and apparently this code will cause syntax error if I just edit like that. Moreover, it would not be able to count variables if C code was like this:

```
int a,b;
```

Only to count once. What move should I make in order to make it work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this (correctly) with just a parser, because the following is a completely legal way of declaring an `int` variable:

```
typedef int MyType;
MyType x;
```

(Typedefs in C are *aliases*, not new types. So there is no difference between `MyType` and `int` after the above.)

It may well be the case that `int32_t` is a type alias for `int`, on a particular platform. So that's not just theoretical.

Even leaving that aside, trying to modify the grammar is probably a lot more work than using the grammar. My suggestion is that you create some kind of representation of types (something like an AST) and then use the semantic action for the variable declaration to see if the type being declared is a simple `int` or something else.

Comment: Note that the referenced grammar requires the addition of a symbol table to differentiate between IDENTIFIERs and TYPEDEF_NAMEs

Comment: @Chris: that's a good point, too. Further reason why semantic analysis is necessary for this problem.

Comment: TY for your answer. So does it mean it does not only need YACC to identify such variables, but Lexical Analyzer? If it were to recognize int array, I should define token INT_ARRAY as like "int "[ ]+[L][L|D]*('['(\\.)']'  ?

Comment: @ta1l: You need a lexical analyser in any case; yacc/bison does not do user input. It relies on a lexical analyser to do that. But that's not what I was talking about. I was talking about what you do with the *result* of the parse.

Comment: The lexical analyser specification in that file is for a very old version of lex, by the way. Although flex continues to be backwards compatible, mostly, you really should attempt to find (or write) an analyser which doesn't rely on legacy features.

Comment: And possibly you should consider starting to learn flex and bison using a simpler problem.